# ударение в слове изгибные

Tags: орфоэпия

Как поставить ударение во множественном числе слова **изгибный**, а именно в слове **изгибные**?

Answer (score 2):

> Как поставить ударение во множественном числе слова ***изгибный***, а
>   именно в слове ***изгибные***?

Правильно: ***изгИбные.***

[**См.:**](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9&all=x)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Вас интересует, смещается ли ударение с корня -гиб- в слове ***изгИбный*** на окончание -ые в форме множественного числа этого слова ***изгибные***?  Не смещается: изгИбные.